# Grouping and aggregating for reports with backbone collection

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, marionette

I have the following information in backbone model and collection form:

```
// Sales model has this type of data
var SalesModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
    defaults:{
        item: "",
        amount: 0
    }
});


// Sales collection has this type of data
var SalesCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({model:SalesModel});

var salesList = new SalesCollection([
    new SalesModel({item: "Icecream", amount: 1}),
    new SalesModel({item: "Pop", amount: 2}),
    new SalesModel({item: "Pop", amount: 4}),
    new SalesModel({item: "Candy", amount: 1}),
    new SalesModel({item: "Pop", amount: 6}),
    new SalesModel({item: "Candy", amount: 3}),
    new SalesModel({item: "Chips", amount: 7}),
    new SalesModel({item: "Corndog", amount: 6}),
]);
```

I am trying to use 'groupBy' and perhaps 'reduce' to create a new collection for a view like this:

ITEM        | SOLD 
Icecream    | 1 
Pop     | 12 
Candy       | 4 
Chips       | 7 
Corndog     | 1

So, you can see that the data has been 'rolled up' with duplicates taken out but totals done. How might I approach this? I have been trying to use groupBy like this:

```
groupedSalesList = salesList.groupBy(function(ss){
    return this.get('item')
});
```

but this fails in jsfiddle. Any help appreciated,

many thanks for your support

Answer (score 1):

At first I want to mention that when you creating/initializing `SalesCollection` you can just pass an array of object and collection will automatically create `SalesModel` models for you because you already defined it:

```
var SalesCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({model:SalesModel});
```

Second note regarding you code that you have invalid groupBy declaration.
Instead of:

```
groupedSalesList = salesList.groupBy(function(ss){
    return this.get('item') // here 'this' reference is window, see example 
});
```

And group by just will return an object not a `Backbone.Collection`

You should use:

> ```
> groupedSalesList = salesList.groupBy(function(model, index, collection){
>     return model.get('item')
> });
> ```

Check for [groupBy](http://underscorejs.org/#groupBy) in underscore.

**And here solution for your problem - [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DzZ8c/2/).**

Here I want to suggest you filter collection of objects before actually creating Backbone collection. I guess this data will be retrieved from server and you could rewrite Backbone's collection parse(resp, options) - (see in Backbone's annotated source) method that used to reformat your response if you need it.

And here is the `groupByMax()` function for your case

> ```
> var groupBySum = function (collection, groupBy, max) {
>     map = collection.reduce(function(memo, item, index, array){
>         memo[item[groupBy]] = (memo[item[groupBy]] || 0) + item[max];    
>         return memo;
>     }, {});        
>     return _.map(map, function(num, key) { 
>         var result = {};
>         result[groupBy] = key;
>         result[max] = num;
>         return result; 
>     });
> };
> ```

`collection` here is an array of objects not a `Backbone.Collection`.

If you want to use `Backbone.Collection` instead you could use `groupBy` sum the values and `reset()` `Backbone.Collection` with new values.

Hope this will help!